# Adobe air ane for android - take screenshot returns black screen

Tags: android, air, adobe, screenshot, ane

I making ane which makes screenshot of application. But I always getting black rectangle.

```
public class TakeScreenshot implements FREFunction {
    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] args) {
        try {
            View view = context.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap cachedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
            Bitmap bitmap = cachedBitmap.copy(cachedBitmap.getConfig(), false);

            FREBitmapData bmd = (FREBitmapData)args[0];
            bmd.acquire();
            bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(bmd.getBits());
            bmd.release();
            bmd.invalidateRect(0,0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
            return bmd;

        } catch (FREWrongThreadException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Guess, the problem is in taking correct View from FREContext. 
Have tried different ways to take View with same result:

```
View view = context.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
View view = context.getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
View view = context.getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot capture SurfaceView renders using this method which is how AIR renders its content.

SurfaceView's will always render as black / empty content using the drawing cache. They contain 2 parts, a placeholder View and the render surface. The drawing cache method only captures the view part which is empty.

On API 21 and higher you can use the [MediaProjection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html) class to perform a screencapture using a virtual display.

This is the method we use in our Image ANE that can capture a screenshot:

https://airnativeextensions.com/extension/com.distriqt.Image

Comment: thank you for your answer, MediaProjection works great.

Can your com.distriqt.Image ane capture screenshots on iOS which contains StageVideo layer with HLS video playback?

I faced with another screenshot-problem :D
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772263/adobe-air-ane-for-ios-take-screenshot-with-stagevideo-layer

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I'm playing a local video but in `Adobe Air Android` I need to take a screenshot `(BITMAPDATA.draw(this);)` the video turns black

Comment: Please don't add *"Me too"* as answers. It doesn't actually provide an answer to the question. If you have a different but related question, then [ask](/questions/ask) it (reference this one if it will help provide context). If you're interested in this specific question, you can [upvote](/help/privileges/vote-up) it, leave a [comment](/help/privileges/comment), or start a [bounty](/help/privileges/set-bounties) once you have enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation).